# Horizontal jquery scroll with mouse detection to also scroll overflow-y in a div

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

So this has been a trouble point for me on this project. What I'm trying to do is create a horizontal scrolling website also with mouse-wheel support, scrolls on X with the wheel.

I also have certain areas of the website or content divs with a set width and height that scroll vertical (overflow-y:scroll). It would be ideal when your mouse is over a vertical scrolling box that you could scroll the contents within.

I made a quick demo using Tiny Scrollbar http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ and have posted that I'm trying to do here:

http://leighmcd.com/slider/demo/

Basically I would like the orange content box to have a vertical scroll when a user has the mouse over the orange.

I have limited JS knowledge to hack up the existing plugin so any advice would be appreciated.

This site is being built for IE8+ users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hover Function with Jquery and some Css tweakings to achieve that,

***HTML***

```
<div id="test">
  Your text goes here...
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
#test
{
  background-color:orange;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

***Jquery***

```
$(document).ready(

    function()
    {
    //Note: overflow:auto will bring the V-scroll bar 
    //at the same time overflow:hidden will hide that.
    $("#test").hover(function(){ $(this).css({"overflow":"auto"}); },
    function(){ $(this).css({"overflow":"hidden"}); });
  }

  );
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BtTzV/1/)

If you need any further clarification, then just visit [this](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: oops, i think ,i Mistook this question and wrongly answered it, can any body show me the directions to how to delete my answer.?

Answer (score 0):

Because I think this topic is interesting I tried a little around.
I figured the easiest way is to do it without the plugin. This is my resulting code to make the page scroll horizontal:

```
// set a block variable if we are over another element that scrolls
// if ie would support e.target for scrolling this wouldn't be needed
var blockScroll = false;
$(".scroller").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function (e) {
  blockScroll = e.type === "mouseenter";
})

function scrollFunc (e) {
  // stop if the target is a .scroller and also
  // if there is an indication that a vertical scroll was done
  if (blockScroll || ("wheelDeltaX" in e && e.wheelDeltaX != 0) || e.shiftKey) return;
  // prevent default scrolling (no jumps)
  e.preventDefault();
  // get ammount of scrolling
  var scroll = "wheelDelta" in e ? -e.wheelDelta : (e.detail * 2);
  // use scroll y for scroll x
  window.scrollBy( scroll, 0 );
}

// try attaching the method like the borwser needs it
// this event isn't covered by jquery so I had to do it manually
if (document.addEventListener) { // W3C sort of
  document.addEventListener( "DOMMouseScroll", scrollFunc, false );
  document.addEventListener( "mousewheel", scrollFunc, false );
} else if (document.attachEvent) { // IE way
  document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollFunc);
} else {
  document.onmousewheel = scrollFunc;
}
```

Note: that every element that scrolls on it's own has to have the class `scroller` with this code. If needed you could try to get the `overflow` value with jquerys `css` but I wouldn't recommend that.

[This is my result](http://jsfiddle.net/2ntAP/13/)! But I have to say that I have no mobile devices to test it there. This solution will only work for mouse wheels.

If you have another element that should scroll horizontal replace the `document` in my example with your element node and `window.scrollBy` with `element.scrollLeft += -scroll`.

I also might have to add that the scrolling will never be as smooth as done directly.

EDIT: I have another idea how this could be accomplished. You could make the page scroll vertical and put a div in it with 100% size and fixed position. Then use the onscroll event to synchronize the horizontal scroll of the inner div with the vertical scroll of the body. I have no idea how well that'll work though.

Comment: I like the idea of what you were going for here but a couple issues I noticed, FF 17.0.1 (Mac) doesnt support the horizontal scroll and on Chrome the browser window tries to scroll vertical causing the browser window to have a jump effect.

Comment: @lemdon Thanks, haven't tested firefox. It should work now. However the scrolling isn't smooth there. Also I implemented a `preventDefault` so the browser won't do anything unexpected.